# I would like to edit data in different format than storing it using Angular x-editable

Tags: angularjs, format, x-editable

I am using Angular X-editable for in-place table editing.  I have a field in my object model that is stored in bits per second.  I don't want the user to have to type this value in bits per second, because it's always going to be a multiple of 1000.  Therefore when the user edits the data, I want the data in the editor to automatically be presented in Kbps, and then when the user types in their Kbps value, convert back to bps to store in the editor.

Example: ng-model is defined as "audio.bitrate". The value 96000 is currently stored in that field.  When the user clicks Edit, I want that text editor to only display 96.  When the user types in another value, such as 128, I want that to be stored in audio.bitrate as 128000.  Is this possible with Angular X-editable?

Comment: should find what you need in the events listed  in the reference section of the docs

Comment: I have tried to solve this using onShow() and onBeforeSave() but have not been able to get it to work correctly.  For now, I have the workaround that I have created a new field on my object, which is the bit rate in kbps, and I have a $watch that makes sure the bps version of the bit rate is updated when the user edits the kbps version.

Comment: makes sense to me and is likely best approach... I think you would have had to change the actual model value using those events otherwise which could be problematic

Comment: I was able to come up with something a little better since my last post. I still have to create my kbps field when the object is first loaded, but now, I am updating the bps field using onaftersave instead of using an expensive $watch.  I saw another post that mentioned that you can pass your object to the onaftersave function, and so I have a very clean way to keep the real field in sync.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment thread on the original question, here was my solution:

1. When the data is read from the REST API, I create a new field in my object called `$$bitRateKbps` that is initialized to 1000x the `bitRate` value.
2. The `editable-text` value points to the `$$bitRateKbps` field.
3. When `onaftersave` is invoked for that field, I call a function `updateBitRateUnits(model)` which updates the `bitRate` field to be `$$bitRateKbps/1000`.
4. Just before posting the data to the REST API, I remove all fields with a $$ prefix.

This seems to be working great.  Thanks to @charlietfl for providing an answer that inspired me to come up with the best solution.